# Generating Transactional Emails for Development purpose

Tags: email, transactional-mail, ee-1.14.0.1

I am working on a bug, which prevents items go be displayed on order confirmation email. Currently, What I am doing is after making changes, to check I have to place order and create a confirmation email. It is tedious and I am sure there should be some way to generate emails for specific orders all you smart folks may know.

I want to know if there is a way to create order confirmation email for particular order, e.g. A script in which we can specify order number and/ or other requred information and it creates generates an email or even better displays out put of email template on console.

Note: This is not same as the preview option, as preview option only displays static elements.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this http://www.magespider.com/magento-send-transactional-email-using-programmatically/  just pass variables you used in template.

Answer (score 1):

You might `exit` the script right after generating the email. This way the quote will remain active and you can place another order just by refreshing the - assumed white - page in your browser (thereby resubmitting your last request).